# Dynamically create columns in SQL select query and join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have 2 tables. They are as follows

Table : Grade

```
GradeID | Grade 
----------------- 
1       | Chopsaw  
2       | Classic
3       | Chieve
```

Table : Moulded Quantity

```
Batch ID | Grade | Moulded | Date 
-------------------------------------
1        | 1     | 150     | 21st May
2        | 1     | 150     | 22nd May
3        | 2     | 150     | 21st May
4        | 2     | 150     | 21st May
5        | 2     | 150     | 22nd May
```

I should get the Output like the following

```
Date       | Moulded  | Chopsaw | Classic | Cieve   
--------------------------------------------------
21st May   | 450      | 150     | 300     | 0    
22nd May   | 300      | 150     | 150     | 0
```

I am using MSSQL 2008 and i use Crystal report to display the same.

Comment: which DB are u using?

Answer (score 3):

If the number of grades is known beforehand then you can do it with a static query.

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(moulded) moulded,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 1 THEN moulded ELSE 0 END) Chopsaw,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 2 THEN moulded ELSE 0 END) Classic,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 3 THEN moulded ELSE 0 END) Chieve
  FROM moulded_quantity 
 GROUP BY date
```

This query is not vendor specific so it should work on any major RDBMS.

Now, if the number of grades is unknown or you want it to work even if you make changes to `grade` table (without changing the query itself) you can resort to dynamic query. But dynamic SQL is vendor specific. Here is an example of how you can do that in MySql

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        'SELECT date, SUM(moulded) moulded,',
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN grade = ',gradeid,
               ' THEN moulded ELSE 0 END) ', grade)),
        ' FROM moulded_quantity GROUP BY date') INTO @sql
FROM grade;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output (in both cases):

```
|     DATE | MOULDED | CHOPSAW | CLASSIC | CHIEVE |
---------------------------------------------------
| 21st May |     450 |     150 |     300 |      0 |
| 22nd May |     300 |     150 |     150 |      0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb09c/41)** demo (for both approaches).

**UPDATE** In Sql Server you can use `STUFF` and `PIVOT` to produce expected result  with dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @colx NVARCHAR(MAX), @colp NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colx = STUFF((SELECT ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Grade) + ',0) ' + QUOTENAME(Grade)
            FROM grade
            ORDER BY GradeID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @colp = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Grade)
            FROM grade
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = 'SELECT date, total moulded, ' + @colx +   
           '  FROM 
            (
              SELECT date, g.grade gradename, moulded,
                     SUM(moulded) OVER (PARTITION BY date) total
                FROM moulded_quantity q JOIN grade g
                  ON q.grade = g.gradeid
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
               SUM(moulded) FOR gradename IN (' + @colp + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY date'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Output is the same as in MySql case.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be9c4/30)** demo.

Comment: He wants it to be dynamically as in not having to make a CASE for each new grade he may add in the future from what I understood.

Comment: @Prix Thanks for input, but I don't see any indication in OP's question to that.

Comment: At his question title `Dynamically create columns`

Comment: just a point, i believe the query should have a group by on `grade`; also Prix has a valid point.

Comment: @NaveenBabu Can you explain why it should be also grouped by `grade`?

Comment: Sorry, I am working on MSSQL. Can you give me a query on this?

Comment: @peterm i actually jumped into that conclusion. So i want to correct my comment about saying "for this o/p expected by user, your groupby is correct, but ideally there should not be a groupby by date field". your case works since you considered the date as varchar. but if it was a date field it would have created issues

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you before asking any question research first as it is very common question.

**Updated**

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS varchar(max) 
SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS+'],[' ,'') +  CAST(Grade as varchar)
FROM Grade
GROUP BY Grade


SET @COLUMNS = '[' + @COLUMNS + ']'


DECLARE @COLUMNS_WITH_NULL varchar(max) 
SELECT @COLUMNS_WITH_NULL  = COALESCE(@COLUMNS_WITH_NULL+',ISNULL([' ,'ISNULL([') +  CAST(Grade as varchar) + '], 0) AS ' +  CAST(Grade as varchar) 
FROM Grade
GROUP BY Grade

DECLARE @COLUMNS_SUMS varchar(max) 
SELECT @COLUMNS_SUMS  = COALESCE(@COLUMNS_SUMS+' + ISNULL([' ,'ISNULL([') +  CAST(Grade as varchar) + '], 0) ' 
FROM Grade
GROUP BY Grade


SET @COLUMNS_SUMS = '(' + @COLUMNS_SUMS + ') as Moulded'
PRINT @COLUMNS_SUMS


EXECUTE (
'
SELECT 
    Date, ' + @COLUMNS_SUMS + ', ' +  @COLUMNS_WITH_NULL + '
FROM (

SELECT 
    m.Moulded,
    m.date AS Date,
    g.Grade
FROM Grade g
INNER JOIN [Moulded Quantity] m
ON m.GRADE = g.GradeID
) up
PIVOT (SUM(Moulded) FOR  Grade IN ('+ @COLUMNS +')) AS pvt')
```

Comment: SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS+'],[' ,'') +  CAST(powerup as varchar) wont work properly as i am not only concerned on single table but also on the fields of other tables too. Any work around for it?

Comment: wait I am taking original columns and tables that you have posted in your qus

Comment: OK. Meantime, am researching from my end too.

Comment: can you mark it as answer, so It could help us to ensure that your problem got solve