# How to choose proper table name dynamically from multiple tables for creating join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I want to create `join` query dynamically which contains following tables:

Table 1) **userTable**: contains userId, userFirstName, userLastName

Table 2) **groupTable**: contains groupId, groupName, groupDescription

Table 3) **userGroup** : contains relation between userTable and groupTable

Table 4) **groupRoles**: contains relations between groupId and roleId (any random column)

***Case1:***

If I want to know in which tables **groupId** is present/common, it gives result like this
[image]

**Query:**

I have 1 form which accepts only userId. By using userId we have to find: userId, userFirstName, userLastName and groupName.

**Problem:**

The problem is while creating dynamic query for `join` clause.

As in case 1 there are 2 options of tables: either groupRoles or userGroup.

So how will I come to know **which table to select from these 2 options dynamically** so that it takes me to the groupTable via relational table which is userGroup table in my case?
As in my case I have to find userId, userFirstName, userLastName and groupName.

I can get the userId, userFirstName and userLastName from userTable. But to get the groupName column which is present in groupTable we have to take userGroup table for relation to get the `join` query.

So how we can come to know which table to select from either of  tableNames (as in case1 ) **dynamically**, so that we can get the GroupName column from query?

Comment: you wants to display the following fields as : Userid,Userfirstname, Userlastname and groupname

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe I've understand your question and do you want the following output As:

```
SELECT 
a.userid,
a.userfirstname,
a.userlastname,
b.groupname
FROM Usertable AS a
INNER JOIN  grouptable AS b
ON a.userid=b.groupid
```

usertable:

```
1| a| b 
2| c| d
```

grouptable:

```
1 |X |io
2 |Y |oi
```

output:

```
1| a| b|X 
2| c| d|Y
```

update:

[try this one to click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142491/3242978)

A generic database design limits the proliferation of new tables as the number of forms and data elements grows. On the other hand even the simplest query involved 3 tables, in our case.

Queries indeed got very mind boggling. After 3 years of this I became of the opinion that explicit tables was better. I'd rather deal with more tables that better reflect the business form/model - that I can understand just by looking at them; vice 1/2 the tables but with multitudes of meaningless join tables requiring astonishing long, nested queries to make even the most rudimentary sense out of the data. You actually start memorizing the meaning/context of individual identity column primary keys!

Finally, we had evolved to where we had that one table to rule them all so as to get away from some of the inherent complexities (and bad coding and design decisions of the past) in the existing design and evolving user requirements. Nonetheless, we were certain we'd have problems as the table size went into the million+ row size.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur reply.But I have to choose tableName dynamically from either of the tables i.e. GROUPROLES or USERGROUP from case1. How I will come to know dynamically that which table to choose according to required query.

Comment: Because both table contains the common column i.e Groupid so that from that relational table I should get the Groupname Column.

Comment: I understood what u are trying to say but as my join query is highly dynamic,I have to use this join query for creating the Form of users where user can ask for any of the detail, that's y I wanted to create query such a way that it could create query and dispaly result according to need.For example as in our case Suppose instead of 'groupname' user ask for 'GroupDescription' then also it should give us proper query result.